# add Value to a column From a .apply function

Tags: pandas

I am trying to apply a simple value to a column to my pandas frame, but always shows NaN, i cant find the reason why.
here is my code.

```
def get_extra_hours(value):
    return f'{value[12] -40: .2f}'

raw_data = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
unified = raw_data.groupby('Employee').sum()
unified['Hourly Rate'] = raw_data.groupby('Employee').first()['Hourly Rate']
unified['Extra Hours'] = raw_data.apply(get_extra_hours, axis=1)

print(unified.to_string())
```

the data in value[12] is a float, i just need take out 40 from value[12] and return with 2 decimal. it can be float or string.

Comment: if you provide sample data it is much easier to help you

Comment: is value[12] just short hand for the 12th column of raw_data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make it work, still  don't understand why didnt work before but here is how i did it

```
def get_extra_hours(value):

    x = value['Total Hours'] - 40
    if x > 0:
        return x
URL = f'https://api.mytimestation.com/v0.1/reports/?api_key={API_KEY}&Report_StartDate={date}&id={CODE}&exportformat=csv'
raw_data = pd.read_csv('testdata.csv')
unified = raw_data.groupby('Employee').sum()
unified['Hourly Rate'] = raw_data.groupby('Employee').first()['Hourly Rate']
unified['Extra Hours'] = unified.apply(get_extra_hours, axis=1)

print(unified.to_string())
```

i change the unified['Extra Hours'] = unified.apply(get_estra_hours, axis=1)
and also change the function get_extra_hours().